# F8 not showing "Advanced Boot Options" on a Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode, malware-removal

**Background**

I'm working on dis-infecting a Windows 7 PC where the user opened a ZIP email attachment.

All the symptoms exactly match [this description of the "Data Recovery" scareware](http://deletemalware.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-remove-data-recovery-uninstall.html), including these messages:

- Windows detected a hard disk problem A potential disk failure may coss loss of files, applications and documents stored on the hard disk. Please try not to use this computer until the hard disk is fixed or replaced.
- Critical Error RAM memory reliability is extremely low. This problem may cause system failure

See the end of this post for details of the machine spec.

**Initial Goal**

I first want to boot the computer in Safe Mode, so that I can run various tools such as [TDSSKiller](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363).

**Trying to boot in Safe Mode**

As the computer starts up, it offers the following options:

- <kbd>Del</kbd> BIOS Setup
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> Display BIOS POST Message
- <kbd>F8</kbd> Boot Menu
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Ez Flash 2

I hoped/expected that pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> would get me into the [Advanced Boot Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode) screen, as for to choose Safe Mode.

However, hitting F8 during start-up only shows the following:

> Please select boot device:
>
> - CDROM:P0-TSSTcorp CDDCDW SH-S22
> - RAID:Intel DATA
> - RAID:INTEL SSDSA2M160G2GC
> - <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> and <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> to move menu selection
> - ENTER to select boot device
> - ESC to boot using defaults

**My question**: Is there something about my machine configuration (see below) that is preventing the Advanced Boot Options menu from showing?

**Machine configuration**

- C: drive is SSD - Intel SSDSA2M160G2GC
- Other partitions are of a RAID 1 pair
- Motherboard: [ASUS P6X58D-E](http://uk.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1366/P6X58DE/)
- OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Comment: For the record, this PC was fully patched and uptodate, and had Microsoft Security Essentials installed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I've found the answer: this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7p852Jp6csE) says that on some computers, F8 brings up the "Select boot device" menu that I described above, and if that happens, to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> then keep hitting <kbd>F8</kbd> until the Advanced Boot Options screen appears.

I'll give it a go.

**Update**

First attempt failed: it just booted normally.

On second attempt, I tapped the <kbd>F8</kbd> as rapidly as I possibly could, after hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, and almost immediately got the Advanced Boot Options menu.

So, I think the issue is that the SSD makes the PC boot so very fast that the standard advice of 'hit the <kbd>F8</kbd> once a second is useless!

(Thankfully, TDSSKiller reported no rootkit, and Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware is now chugging away, and finding stuff to remove, so things are looking up, relatively speaking)

Comment: This is correct! Most new ASUS boards use F8 to select the boot device, and this happens before you get the chance to use the Windows option (*this is a very lousy design choice in my opinion*).  Then, your SSD loads so fast you only have a very brief window to enter Safe Mode at all!  You should just go ahead and mark this as the answer because, well, it is.

Comment: For me it didn't work with the `esc` and then press `f8`. I had a little different problem, because when I hit `f8` the first time I got to a somewhat the same thing. For me it was also an option to enter Windows boot options. When I entered there I only started the computer in a regular way, but when I hit `Enter`, and then `f8` I could get to safe mode.

Comment: `F8 + ESC + F8 + ESC + F8 + ESC + F8 + ESC + F8` did the job... damn windows

Answer (score 1):

This is not for booting into safe mode - but I had a very similar problem which was trying to access the Advanced Boot menu so that I could re-install Windows 7.

I have the [ASUS P7H55-M SI motherboard](http://www.novatech.co.uk/products/components/motherboards/intel1156h55,h57,q57chipset/ASU-H55MSI.html) with Windows 64-bit and I found that <kbd>F8</kbd> simply wasn't the correct key. <kbd>F8</kbd> does as suggested here bring up the 'Select boot device', but for me it would never go to the Advanced Boot menu after - no matter how quickly I pressed <kbd>F8</kbd>. In the end after reading the [manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/438747/Asus-P7h55-M-Si.html?page=46#manual) which suggests that <kbd>F5</kbd> is the magic key (which it wasn't either), I tried going through all of <kbd>F2</kbd> - <kbd>F9</kbd>.

For me it turned out the <kbd>F3</kbd> was the magic key although it didn't bring up the Advanced Boot menu, it took me direct to the '[System Recovery Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7)' menu that is what you get if you go to the Advanced Boot menu and select 'Repair Your Computer'.