# My HP won't show advanced boot options

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, hp-pavilion

My HP desktop won't show advance boot options when I hit <kbd>F8</kbd>

It shows my processor information and so on when pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter startup menu. I'm so frustrated I cant go into safe mode.

I tried to hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and it shows the same screen
as described above. I've tried to find information on other forums.

On the startup menu it displays the BIOS and Hewlett Packard utilities and other settings

Comment: please spend some time on basic grammar and formatting of your post also add specific details about your computer model and of what you see finally remove everything that is not related to your question if you expect people to spend time on helping you it's nice for them to see you bothered yourself and spent some time on your question as well now it's just a wall of text i'm not going to take seriously and yes one of the downvotes is mine just for that very reason

Comment: @PHASUSANAMORNTHEPADUN What OS ?

Comment: Depending on your model, I believe there is a special function key assigned. Please post the model as suggested.

Comment: its windows 7 hp pavillion 3.30 gigahertz

Comment: build 7601 hp 20111 monitor

Comment: intel core i3 2120

Comment: Very unlikely, but he might be asking about enabling the hp bios advanced options? There are boot settings made available with that enabled. On most HPs hit the A key repeatedly after hitting the 'enter bios' key (f8 usually on hps).

Comment: @PHASUSANAMORNTHEPADUN Try this post http://superuser.com/a/346312/270195 It says you must press `Esc` before you start pressing `F8` Also, Are you sure `F8` is working ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the legacy Advanced Options menu like W7, and you have Windows 8 or 10, you can revert the bootloader to legacy mode so F8 works like it did with Windows 7.

Open an elevated (Administrator) Command Prompt and type the following command:

> bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy

Spaces in this command are important, restart and try F8 now, you should get the legacy Advanced Boot Options screen now.

.

To revert these changes if needed:

> bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard

Comment: I am assuming this was posted assuming OP has Windows 8 or higher however he commented he has Windows 7.

Comment: Yep they update info after I have answered. Not sure what their problem is other than operator error.

Comment: Had it with Sony or a Samsung long time ago where I had to press F5 instead of F8 but OP's case could be anything. A faulty F8 key or a need to press Esc before starting to press F8

Comment: HP uses F8, operator error I tell ya.