# How to repair "windows host" error for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, malware

I got a Dell computer and my operating system is Windows 7. The other day, I downloaded something which caused a virus and adware, also installing things that were scams (stuff that wasn't what it said to be).  Well, I got rid of all the stuff I could see that had been installed, but the next day my whole background is gone (even the Windows taskbar).

Luckily, I was able to get on a browser from the task manager (the new task button) but my computer isn't working properly. The performance is poor, and I get this warning when I get on the computer saying "window host" on the top and something about vbscript in the body message.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Reboot the OS, during the reboot-phase press and release F8 until the Manager is shown "Advanced Boot Options" and choose "Last know good configuration". If it doesn't work something else could be tried. Here is a link for a similar Problem:                                   https://superuser.com/questions/346309/f8-not-showing-advanced-boot-options-on-a-windows-7-pc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: As a short-term solution, I would use a different/clean computer to download [RKill](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/) and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/), then run both of them in that order and remove whatever they find.  Realistically, if the operating system is that problematic the *only* safe method to return it back to normal is a full wipe-and-reload.

Comment: i have malwarebytes but it never stays open when i open it.... it loses response instantly, but ok ill try to use it